# NodeJS autorefresh server

Tags: node.js, netbeans

Ok, I'm using **NetBeans** and I have this piece of code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.send("Hi"); 
});

app.listen(8000);
```

When I click run file it starts listening on the port 8000. But, when I **make a change** and then **run** file again it **cannot start** listening on port 8000, because the previous one was not terminated. I have the option **checked** "Apply Code Changed on Save" in Options->HTML/JS->Node.js. How to refresh previously started server instead of starting the new one one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the project in NetBeans was set to be run as WebApplication, but not as NodeJS Application and thus it didn't start the nodeJS server. In order to change it you have to right click on your project and go to "Properties"->"Run" and then change "Run As:" to "Node.js Application" and check "Restart running Node.js process".

Answer (score 0):

The 'Apply Code Changed on Save' is imho for debugging. You can run the project instead of file, if you run project and it has been already running, then NetBeans will stop the running project (e.g to free the port) and it will continue and run the projec

Comment: When I Run the project it opens chrome with index.html in a debug mode, but the server doesn't start. I have to manually click on a file and click "run file", but then when I change something i need to manually stop the server in order to run it again.

Comment: Make sure to have configured what file is being used on "Run project" action. Right click on the project, select Project Properties and category Run. In the "Run As" select "NodeJS Application" . There you need to specify the desire JS file and you can check the "Restart running Node.js process". Take a look at http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/a/a6/Nb81-nodejs-8.png . Note that you need to specify Site Root if you want to also open web browser on project run. More information http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Node.js_Support

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out.